# Retornar substring definida por blocos em Python, na primeira ocorrência

Tags: python, regex

Em python, estou tentando capturar uma substring definida por blocos, contudo a palavra "blocos" se repete no texto e gostaria de obter a substring até a **primeira** ocorrência desta. Neste exemplo o retorno traz até a última ocorrência:

```
import re
TXT = "Este é um texto de teste para verificar a captura de blocos que estão dentro de uma String. E agora inserimos outros blocos para confundir."
texto = re.search("teste.*blocos", TXT)
print(texto[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o quantificador `*` é [ganancioso (*greedy quantifier*)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy): ele tenta pegar o máximo possível de caracteres que satisfaça a expressão.

Para cancelar a ganância, basta colocar um `?` logo depois do `*`:

```
texto = re.search("teste.*?blocos", TXT)
```

Com isso, será capturado apenas o trecho até a primeira ocorrência de `blocos`.

Como `*?` pega o mínimo necessário para satisfazer a expressão, é chamado de [quantificador preguiçoso (*lazy quantifier*)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy).

---

Apenas um detalhe, se sua string for como o exemplo abaixo:

```
TXT = "teste com cablocos com blocos que tem mais blocos."
texto = re.search("teste.*?blocos", TXT)
```

O trecho capturado será `teste com cablocos`. Se quiser somente a palavra `blocos` (e não `cablocos`), use `\b` para delimitar a palavra:

```
TXT = "teste com cablocos com blocos que tem mais blocos."
texto = re.search(r"teste.*?\bblocos\b", TXT)
```

Com isso, o trecho capturado será `teste com cablocos com blocos`.

Detalhe que agora usei `r"teste..."` para criar uma *raw string*, pois assim o caractere `\` não precisa ser escapado. Sem o `r`, eu teria que escrevê-lo como `\\`:

```
# sem o r"..." o caractere "\" deve ser escrito como "\\"
texto = re.search("teste.*?\\bblocos\\b", TXT)
```

Como `\` é um caractere bastante usado em expressões regulares, é interessante usar *raw strings* para deixar a expressão menos confusa.

---

*<sup>Eu sei que a palavra correta é "caboclos", mas não consegui achar um exemplo melhor.</sup>*